# vba Bad file name or number

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem. This is a code

```
Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If FolderExist(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    fso.CreateFolder path
    Exit Function
End If

End Function

Function FolderExist(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    FolderExist = False
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExist = True
End Function
```

i try too create folder U:\Paweł\Generator\Akus Marcin 20180108001
and i get a bad file name or number.

when i try to create other folder like this U:\Paweł\Generator\Bedrunka Brunon 20171219001 there is no problem. What's wrong with the name of the folder?
thanks for the answer

Comment: Does you `FolderExist` work correctly?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but shouldn't you be setting the return value to `False` if nothing is created?

Comment: yes, work correctly. Folder name: Bedrunka Brunon 20171219001 create with no problem.

Comment: this is my code for FolderExist:

    Function FolderExist(ByVal path As String) As Boolean


    FolderExist = False
                                            

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject


    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExist = True
             

    End Function

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question, but possibly a solution to the problem, with code using `MkDir` that has been tested and acknowledged by others.

```
Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
    'Dim strDir As String 
    'strDir = "C:\My Documents\TestDir\" 
    If Dir(path, vbDirectory) = "" Then 
        MkDir path
        FolderCreate = True
    Else 
        MsgBox "Directory exists." 
        FolderCreate = False
    End If 
End Function
```

From your code it is not clear if you want the assignments of the return value as I used, the opposite, or something else.
You may modify this.

Source: adapted from http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?7866-Check-for-folder-create-if-it-does-not-exist

---

You may also try other tested code, or take snippets from there...

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4182-excel-check-if-folder-exists.html

Comment: i create with my code 43 folders and many times code FolderExist was in use. Maybe wrong name of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with the folders I created.  No references need to be set as it's using Late Binding.

```
Sub Test()

    CreateFolder "U:\Pawel\Generator\Akus Marcin 20180108001"
    CreateFolder "U:\Pawel\Generator\Bedrunka Brunon 20171219001"

End Sub

Sub CreateFolder(Folder As String)

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    With oFSO
        If Not .FolderExists(Folder) Then
            .CreateFolder Folder
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Testing with your code didn't return any errors either.  If my code returns errors it may be a system setting that's stopping the folder being created (but that doesn't explain why one folder gets created while the other doesn't in the same parent folder).

Comment: I find a solution. There is a problem with surname "Akus". When i wrote "AKUS" there is no problem. I don't no why is a problem with "Akus".